# Variable sized lookahead consume

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Im a trying to use a regular expression to parse a varying string using php, that string can be, for example;

```
"twoX // threeY"
```

or

```
"twoX /// threeY"
```

So there is a left-keyword, a `divider` consisting of 2 or 3 slashes and a right-keyword. These are also the parts I would like to consume separately.

```
"/((?<left>.+)?)(?=(?<divider>[\/]{2,3}))([\/]{2,3})((?<right>.+)?)/";
```

When I use this regular expression on the first string, everything gets parsed correctly, so;

> **left**: twoX
>
> **divider**: //
>
> **right**: threeY

but when I run this expression on the second string, the *left* and the *divider* don't get parsed properly. The result I then get is;

> **left**: twoX /
>
> **divider**: //
>
> **right**: threeY

I do use the *{2,3}* in the regular expression to either select 2 or 3 slashes for the divider. But this somehow doesn't seem to work with the match-all character .

Is there a way to get the regex to parse either 2 or 3 slashes without duplicating the entire sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is easy, you need to use `(?<left>.*?)` instead of `(?<left>.+)?`

Comment: Why can't you just split the statement with `\s*/+\s*` ? Instead of using `\s` you can also use ` ` (literal space character), too, as `\s` will also match other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(.+)?` is a greedy dot matching pattern and matches as many chars as possible with 1 being the minimum. So, since the next pattern requires only 2 chars, only 2 chars will be captured into the next group, the first `/` will belong to Group 1.

Use a *lazy* pattern in the first group:

```
'~(?<left>.*?)(?<divider>/{2,3})(?<right>.*)~'
          ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKF5Gn/1). Add `^` and `$` anchors around the pattern to match the whole string if necessary.

Note you do not need to repeat the same pattern in the lookahead and the consuming pattern part, it only makes the pattern cumbersome, `(?=(?<divider>[\/]{2,3}))([\/]{2,3})` = `(?<divider>[\/]{2,3})`.

**Details**

- `(?<left>.*?)` - Group "left" that matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars as **few** as possible
- `(?<divider>/{2,3})` - 2 or 3 slashes (no need to escape since `~` is used as a regex delimiter)
- `(?<right>.*)` - Group "right" matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars as **many** as possible (up to the end of line).

And a more natrual-looking splitting approach, see a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BYzh9x):

```
$s = "twoX // threeY";
print_r(preg_split('~\s*(/{2,3})\s*~', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
// => Array ( [0] => twoX [1] => // [2] => threeY )
```

You lose the names, but you may add them at a later step.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation and the alternative _(. _ .)_

Answer (score 2):

The `+` quantifier is greedy by default, meaning that it will try and match as many characters as possible. So you want to make the first `+` lazy so it will not try and match the first `/` by adding the `?` quantifier you can make the `+` lazy: `+?`.
This will result in the following regex:

```
((?<left>.+?)?)(?=(?<divider>[\/]{2,3}))([\/]{2,3})((?<right>.+)?)
```

Comment: And what is the purpose of the lookahead here? You repeat the same mistake as OP. It is redundant, the lookahead pattern can be used in the consuming pattern and the whole regex will look much cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Also, why use `(?<left>.+?)?`? you require at least 1 char and then say "ok, match 1 char, but 1 or 0 times". Isn't it more natural to say "match 0 or more chars", `(?<left>.*?)`?

Comment: @Wiktor I only adjusted the original regex to fix  the problem in the question, and haven't really looked at the other parts of the regex. Looking at it again (and looking at your answer) I see what you mean. While this also solves the problem in the question, I think your answer is by far the better answer.